# Why my easypie number don't show inside?

Tags: jquery, html, css, easypie

I'm using [easypie](http://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/) plugin.
But, the number isn't showing inside the pie and I don't know why. I already try many things.
How to put number inside the pie?
I'm using this css:

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADZP8/)**

```
.easychart {
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 margin:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS is fine:

```
.easychart {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin:10px;
}
```

You actually forgot to bring in the required [**CSS file**](http://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/stylesheets/jquery.easy-pie-chart.css). Check the update: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ADZP8/3/).

Please see the [**documentation**](http://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/).

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine you just need to add css resources as you're already having bootstrap you need to set **jquery.easy-pie-chart.js**

```
.easychart {
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 margin:10px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADZP8/4/)